# What can I do if I insist want to load image from local C drive to my IE9 browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, image, jsp

Like most of the people has asked the similar question. But so far, I didn't found a solution yet.

```
var img = [

   C:/a/b/1.png,
   C:/a/b/2.png
];

$j.each(img, function(){
    $j('#imagesList').append('<li><img src=file:///"' + this + '" /></li>'); 
});
```

Comment: Are you running a local web server?

Comment: Yes. I am running on local web server. But my client will need to load his local image file to the web browser.

Comment: You will not be able to do that due to security restrictions on client-side coding unless you have the client install a web-server. Why do you need to operate this way rather than uploading images to a website?

Comment: I will need to do that as customer requested. And fire is on the butt.

Comment: Your customer will need to save the web pages locally for this to work. See [JS Same-Domain Security info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy) for more explanation why.

Comment: you need to advise your customer about security issues and why things like this are not allowed and then point him in the right direction.

Comment: I saved the image file at my server and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first make array like this

```
var img = [

   "C:/a/b/1.png",
   "C:/a/b/2.png"
];
```

then

```
$j.each(img, function(i, val){
    $j('#imagesList').append('<li><img src=file:///"' + val + '" /></li>'); 
});
```

Comment: This assumes that the local browser can run properly locally without a web server. Not all browsers will work.

Comment: as expected, this solution is not working. As I saw some forum discussion, it only applicable to <IE7

Answer (score 0):

Your browser security prevents loading images from local hard disks.
A long time ago this was allowed, you could even load an image from something like D:/ and ope n the CD drive.

Comment: It might be possible through file APIs if the user explicitly picks the file from a dialog (no need to upload). But I'm not even sure if those APIs are available on IE9, so yeah, this might not be possible (probably not how the OP wants it)